# How to exclude Hyper-V switch from Network Location Awareness

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 Pro (1903) with the Hyper-V role.

I need an Internal network switch so I can community from my host to my VM with static IPs. The "Default Switch" Hyper-V adds changes its IP range on every reboot.

I need to exclude this network adapter from Network Location Awareness. I know this must be possible as the "Default Switch" and "nat" (added by Docker) don't show anything other Network Category on my [Network Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD9oh.png) (see image) screen.

Switching the network interface to private via Powershell doesn't persist between reboots, so that is not ideal. Nor is changing the group policy to make all unidentified networks private due to the security concerns (this is a laptop).

Comment: i have Problems to follow your request, even to say that win 20 isnt a good choice for hosting, normally if you have the  switch setup'ed you are free to use your own ip range, normally?

Comment: "Switching the network interface to private via Powershell doesn't persist between reboots,.." 
Why not use scheduled tasks, with a trigger @startup and a delay maybe?